# Bad handshake error with hue oozie server

Tags: ssl, openssl, oozie, hue

I am trying to connect hue with ssl enabled oozie server, but facing the below SSL issue.

```
Error submitting workflow Batch job for query-pig: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)
```

Created CA certificate from oozie server machine and configured it with hue server.

I could able to get the status information from oozie server using curl command with the help of certificate that i have generated. But issue occurs only when communicating from hue server.

Also added proxy user in oozie-site.xml properties.

hue.ini

```
       [liboozie]
      # The URL where the Oozie service runs on. This is required in order for
      # users to submit jobs. Empty value disables the config check.
      oozie_url=https://Fully Qualified Host name:11443/oozie

      # Requires FQDN in oozie_url if enabled
      security_enabled=true
      use_libpath_for_jars=false
      # Location on HDFS where the workflows/coordinator are deployed when submitted.
      remote_deployement_dir=/user/hue/oozie/deployments
      ssl_cert_ca_verify=true
```

I dont know what is the difference while connecting from curl and hue server as curl works perfectly for me where hue server doesn't.

Comment: As far as I understand ,you are using a self-signed certificate for Oozie. I think trust between Oozie and Hue is not set up properly. I hope the following might help you:
- https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cm_sg_ssl_hue.html
- http://harshj.com/trusting-self-signed-ssl-certificates-in-cloudera-hue/